# Mapbox production error in console. "Uncaught ReferenceError: y is not defined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, mapbox-gl, react-map-gl

I have a full-stack React.js application deployed on Heroku. Everything deployed fine except for Mapbox. In development, everything works nice. As soon as I open my application in Heroku, Mapbox displays a black screen.

I have added config vars in Heroku for the default public Mapbox token.

When I check the console in production, I am getting an error saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: y is not defined"

I'm using Mapbox with React Map GL, and not sure what the issue is, looking for help at this point.

I have added a screenshot of how it looks in development and the black screen I get in production.[production-mapbox-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2Krc.png) [development-mapbox-working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB6wl.jpg)

**my client-side package.json:**

```
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.8",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "framer-motion": "^3.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.14.1",
    "react-map-gl": "^6.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
}
```

**my ReactMapGL component:**

```
import ReactMapGL, { Marker, Popup } from "react-map-gl";
import { listLogEntries } from "./api";
import MapPin from "../../assets/icons/map-pin1.svg";
import MapPinRed from "../../assets/icons/map-pin-red1.svg";
import LogEntryForm from "../LogEntryForm/logEntryForm";
import "./reactMap.scss";

const ReactMap = () => {
  const [logEntries, setLogEntries] = useState([]);
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState({});
  const [addEntryLocation, setAddEntryLocation] = useState(null);
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    width: "100vw",
    height: "100vh",
    latitude: 49.246292,
    longitude: -123.116226,
    zoom: 8,
  });

  const getEntries = async () => {
    const logEntries = await listLogEntries();
    setLogEntries(logEntries);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getEntries();
  }, []);

  const showAddMarkerPopup = (event) => {
    const [longitude, latitude] = event.lngLat;
    setAddEntryLocation({
      longitude,
      latitude,
    });
  };

  const MAP = process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN;
  const MAP_STYLE = process.env.REACT_APP_MAP_STYLE;
  return (
    <div className="map">
      <ReactMapGL
        className="map__react-gl"
        {...viewport}
        // Setting map theme from mapbox
        mapStyle={MAP_STYLE}
        // mapbox Api Access Token
        mapboxApiAccessToken={MAP}
        onViewportChange={setViewport}
        onDblClick={showAddMarkerPopup}
      >
        {logEntries.map((entry) => (
          <div key={entry._id}>
            <Marker latitude={entry.latitude} longitude={entry.longitude}>
              <div
                onClick={() =>
                  setShowPopup({
                    [entry._id]: true,
                  })
                }
              >
                <img
                  className="map__pin"
                  style={{
                    width: `${4 * viewport.zoom}px`,
                    height: `${4 * viewport.zoom}px`,
                  }}
                  src={MapPin}
                  alt="Map Pin"
                />
              </div>
            </Marker>
            {showPopup[entry._id] ? (
              <Popup
                className="map__popup"
                latitude={entry.latitude}
                longitude={entry.longitude}
                dynamicPosition={true}
                closeButton={true}
                closeOnClick={false}
                onClose={() => setShowPopup({})}
                anchor="top"
              >
                <div className="map__info-container">
                  <h3 className="map__info-heading">{entry.title}</h3>
                  <hr className="map__hr" />
                  <p className="map__info-description">{entry.description}</p>
                  <hr className="map__hr" />
                  <p className="map__info-comment">{entry.comments}</p>
                  <div className="map__info-image-container">
                    {entry.image && (
                      <img
                        className="map__image"
                        src={entry.image}
                        alt={entry.title}
                      />
                    )}
                  </div>
                  <small className="map__info-visited">
                    Visited on: {new Date(entry.visitDate).toLocaleDateString()}
                  </small>
                </div>
              </Popup>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        ))}
        {addEntryLocation ? (
          <div>
            <Marker
              latitude={addEntryLocation.latitude}
              longitude={addEntryLocation.longitude}
            >
              <div>
                <img
                  className="map__pin-red"
                  style={{
                    width: `${4 * viewport.zoom}px`,
                    height: `${4 * viewport.zoom}px`,
                  }}
                  src={MapPinRed}
                  alt="Map Pin"
                />
              </div>
            </Marker>
            <Popup
              className="map__popup"
              latitude={addEntryLocation.latitude}
              longitude={addEntryLocation.longitude}
              dynamicPosition={true}
              closeButton={true}
              closeOnClick={false}
              onClose={() => setAddEntryLocation(null)}
              anchor="top"
            >
              <div className="map__new-info-container">
                <LogEntryForm
                  onClose={() => {
                    setAddEntryLocation(null);
                    getEntries();
                  }}
                  location={addEntryLocation}
                />
                <form action=""></form>
              </div>
            </Popup>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </ReactMapGL>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReactMap;
```

Answer (score 16):

This is an issue of Webpack. For any future viewers, here's what worked for me:

```
import ReactMapGL, {Marker} from 'react-map-gl'
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
mapboxgl.workerClass = require('worker-loader!mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl-csp-worker').default;
```

Also, remember to npm install worker-loader.

Comment: I tried this it did not work. see my entry https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/issues/1266#issuecomment-1342855342

Answer (score 4):

So after some more research, I found that the problem is in the version of react-map-gl (6.0.2). Installing react-map-gl@5.2.5 finally displayed my Layers and everything works fine. I don't know what is the problem in version 6.0.2. Hope they will fix this soon.

Comment: thanks, i have downgraded my version to mapbox-gl@1.13.0

Comment: maybe i should try downgrading it, i tried everything it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I had a related error using maplibre-gl (a fork of mapbox). The reason for me was `create-react-app` generates configuration that targets older browsers in the production build than in the development build. So in the development build, things worked. But in the production build they did not.

To fix in this case, update the browserlist configuration to target newer browsers (https://github.com/maplibre/maplibre-gl-js/issues/1011).

Answer (score 0):

simply put
`"production": ["defaults", "not ie 11"]` instead of `"production": [">0.2%", "not dead", "not op_mini all"]` in the package.json file. In some cases it is suggested to keep `not op_mini all`.